# Qual é o fonema para o R no final de palavras?

Tags: fonologia

Existe bastante alofonia e supressão do fonema marcado pela letra R no final de diversas palavras, como em amar (e no final de todos os infinitivos), interior, mulher, etc.

Minha dúvida é: *qual* fonema é esse?

Comment: Se estiveres perguntando qual fonema é esse R, foneticamente falando, que é o que imagino que queres, há várias possibilidades, variando entre dialetos. No meu dialeto, se entre vogais /ɾ/, senão /ɹ/; no dialeto paulista, /ɾ/. O som desse R é um dos sons variantíssimos da língua portuguesa, então, há várias respostas à tua pergunta, se eu a interpretei corretamente. No meu dialeto, apenas há supressão de R final em infinitivos.

Answer (score 3):

## Portugal

Em Portugal, o r no fim de palavras é **/ɾ/, vibrante simples alveolar** (Wikipedia: [en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental_and_alveolar_taps_and_flaps) / [pt](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrante_simples_alveolar)).

Em http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=fonetica&act=list podes consultar um dicionário fonético.
Tem um campo para pesquisa do lado direito:

- [Amar](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=fonetica&act=list&region=lbx&search=amar);
- [Interior](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=fonetica&act=list&region=lbx&search=interior);
- [Mulher](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=fonetica&act=list&region=lbx&search=mulher).

A pronúncia de r no final de palavras em Portugal não é muito variada.
Entre vogais, sim já varia mais: costuma ser /ɾ/, mas no norte também há quem use /r/.

## Brasil

[Segundo o Schilive num comentário da tua pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8284/r-final-de-palavras#comment18733_8284), no Brasil é também /ɾ/ no dialeto paulista, mas no dele é **/ɹ/, aproximante alveolar** (Wikipedia: [en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_alveolar_and_postalveolar_approximants) / [pt](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aproximante_alveolar)):

> Se estiveres perguntando qual fonema é esse R, foneticamente falando, que é o que imagino que queres, há várias possibilidades, variando entre dialetos. No meu dialeto, se entre vogais /ɾ/, senão /ɹ/; no dialeto paulista, /ɾ/. O som desse R é um dos sons variantíssimos da língua portuguesa, então, há várias respostas à tua pergunta, se eu a interpretei corretamente. No meu dialeto, apenas há supressão de R final em infinitivos.

No Brasil os dialetos variam bastante mais que em Portugal.
Uma resposta exaustiva vai ser mais complexa.